# Cannot retreive CSP header with python

Tags: python, http, header, response, content-security-policy

I want to retrieve all headers from a certain site, in this example "https://www.facebook.com" as following:

```
import urllib2
enter code here`req = urllib2.Request('https://www.facebook.com/')
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print res.info()
res.close();
```

that results in this response:

```
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: sb=1GyeWkJzGbmX-VUyBi26; expires=Thu, 05-Mar-2020 10:26:28 GMT; Max-Age=63071999; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; secure; httponly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-FB-Debug: X9aSOOKs6/aER1yuY4iUUIZrj4yTKtKSUAZ/AFE37IieCe8O4MSsFc5xlQ0LoQyHnbrSL4DaYiTVUUkFZeDrsqqg==
Date: Tue, 06 Mar 2018 10:26:29 GMT
Connection: close
```

I can retrieve all headers except for the Content-Security-Policy (csp);
But whenever I test on [geekflare csp test](https://tools.geekflare.com/report/csp-test/https://www.facebook.com)
It succesfully retrieved all headers including the csp one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I forgot to set the User-Agent within the request.